# Index an element of BitVec in Z3Py

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

Is there a way to index an element in a `BitVec`? I'd like to something like this:

```
s = Solver()
x = BitVec('x', 8)
s.add(Not(And(x[0], x[2])))
```

Or is masking the the only way to isolate bits:

```
s.add(x & 5 != 5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Extract(high, low, a)`](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3py_8py_source.html#l03858) to extract one, or more, bits from a term of `BitVec` type.

**e.g.**

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
x = BitVec("x", 8)

x_0 = Extract(0, 0, x)
x_2 = Extract(2, 2, x)

expr = Or(x_0 == 0, x_2 == 0)

s.add(expr)

while s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print("Model: " + str(m))

    v_0 = m.eval(x_0)
    v_2 = m.eval(x_2)

    bl = Or(x_0 != v_0, x_2 != v_2)

    s.add(bl)
```

Output:

```
Model: [x = 4]    # 0000 0100
Model: [x = 0]    # 0000 0000
Model: [x = 1]    # 0000 0001
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Should really go into some sort of a Z3 FAQ.

Comment: @patricktrentin Wonderful, do you know how this is internally represented? Specifically does your answer allow an internal SAT representation? I imagine my masking approach, `s.add(x & 5 != 5)` would be slower because it generates useless clauses. A follow-up question is how are bit-vectors represented internally? Are they Ints or atoms?

Comment: @HiDefender AFAIK, both your and mine solution admit a SAT representation, see, e.g.,  [A Tale of Two Solvers: Eager and Lazy Approaches to Bit-vectors](https://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~tinelli/papers/HadEtAl-CAV-14.pdf); I would prefer to avoid making any guess about the efficiency of an encoding without running a small experiment first;

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Ran a quick experiment on my current project with each type of constraint.

Constraints like this `[ (G[i] & BitVecVal(5, 12))  != BitVecVal(5, 12)  for i in range(len(grapheme)) ]` averaged 1.86 seconds.

Constraints like this `[ Not(And(Extract(2, 2, G[i]) == 1, Extract(0, 0, G[i]) == 1))  for i in range(len(grapheme)) ]` averaged 1.43 seconds.